# Split items into two columns CSS grid

Tags: css, css-grid

Is there a way to achieve the following via CSS grid?

1. If the number of items is odd, the first column should have 1 more row than the second column.

```
1 4
2 5
3
```

2. If the number of items is even, the columns should have the same number of rows.

```
1 3 
2 4
```

Tried using `grid-template-rows` but the number of rows per column is fixed.

Comment: No. the number of rows is required to be stated for this to work and even then CSS can't actually *count* how many items there are.

Comment: it will always be 5 or 4 elements? if yes, it's possible

Comment: @TemaniAfif no, it's either odd or even number of elements.

Comment: I updated my answer to cover the generic case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the question explicitly states "via CSS grid", I think it's worth adding an easy way to do this *without* grid. Especially since all grid-based approaches seem to require you to hard-code the number of desired rows.

Two divide any number of items in to two columns, you can use the `column-count` css property like so: `column-count: 2`.

This property meets the requirements for:

- going top-to-bottom before left-to-right,
- balancing the columns, prioritizing the first column when there is an odd number of elements

```css
#twocol {
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="twocol">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
  <div>Item 4</div>
  <div>Item 5</div>
  <div>Item 6</div>
</div>

<button onclick="twocol.innerHTML += `<div>Item ${twocol.children.length + 1}</div>`">Add item</button>
```

Comment: Ahhh super late but exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Actually, not exactly what I was looking for. The grid was for the cells to have the same height as well. What happens with `column-count` is it splits the container into n columns to distribute the items so the columns have the same heights.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATED: Added two more options how to handle it by HTML/CSS.
What about using `grid`? There is 3 options, how it can be done:

1. Using default item order;
2. Using CSS variable, where you can define row number to break;
3. Using additional class, added to child item, after wich it's siblinks will go to next column;

```css
/* Option-1. Default */
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(50px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  width: fit-content;
}

.container > div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--color, tomato);
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}
/* End of Option-1. */

/* Option-2. With additional class */
.container--with-break {
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
.container--with-break > div {
  grid-column: 1;
}
.container--with-break > .break ~ div {
  grid-column: 2;
}
/* End of Option-2. */

/* Option-3. With CSS variable */
.container--with-break-row {
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--break-row), 1fr);
}
/* End of Option-3. */

/* Example stylings */
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  align-items: start;
  width: fit-content;
}

hr {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
/* End of Ex. stylings */
```

```html
<p>Option with default order</p>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr />

<p>Option with changing order. Using CSS variables</p>
<div 
  class="wrapper"
  style="--color: mediumturquoise;"
>
  <div 
    class="container container--with-break-row"
    style="--break-row: 3;"
  >
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
  </div>
  
  <div 
    class="container container--with-break-row"
    style="--break-row: 2;"
  >
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
  
  <div 
    class="container container--with-break-row"
    style="--break-row: 3;"
  >
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
  </div>
  
  <div 
    class="container container--with-break-row"
    style="--break-row: 4;"
  >
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr />

<p>Option with changing order. Using additional class to child item</p>
<div 
  class="wrapper"
  style="--color: mediumpurple;"
>
  <div class="container container--with-break">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div class="break">3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container container--with-break">
    <div>1</div>
    <div class="break">2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Randy could be an option, if you have 4-5 element max. but anyway I prefer not to hardcode things

Comment: You could re-arrange the HTML elements to get the layout asked for in the question.
I would think if you split the elements into two sections, first half and second half, then you can alternate between the first and second half to get this list dynamically.

Comment: dense will do nothing here since the elements are placed using the default algorithm. dense is only useful when we give explicit placement to some elements

Comment: @TemaniAfif you are right, I was trying another way to handle it, and forgot to remove (and later described it above) Removed unused code.

Comment: Already tried this but really need it to be top to bottom, left to right.

Comment: @dork I've updated my answer, added two more options how it can be handled.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of items is always 4 or 5 you can do the following:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  justify-content: start;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.container>div {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* create the extro row for the case of odd items */
.container>div:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(odd) {
  grid-row: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

For the generic case like below

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: dense; /* you need this */
  justify-content: start;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.container>div {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* create the extro row for the case of odd items */
.container>div:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(odd) {
  grid-row: 3;
}
/* all odd items counting from the end at the second row*/
.container > div:nth-last-child(odd) {
 grid-row: 2;
}

/* the first and second item should never change*/
.container > div:first-child {
 grid-row: 1;
}
.container > div:nth-child(2) {
 grid-row: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying Yaro's answer:

```
<div style="display: grid; grid-auto-flow: column; grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr)">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Is all you need. This results in the items going:

```
1    4
2    5
3
```

instead of

```
1    2
3    4
5
```

Since we split it into 3 rows with `repeat(3, 1fr)`.

Answer (score -1):

Credits for the grid go to @YaroslavTrach but the order of HTML elements can be achieved by splitting your elements into two arrays and then alternating between them when rendering.

```js
const elements = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
const half = Math.ceil(elements.length / 2);

const firstHalf = elements.slice(0, half);
const secondHalf = elements.slice(-half + 1);

const toDiv = (i) => i ? `<div>${i}</div>` : ``;

document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = `
  ${firstHalf.map((el, id) => toDiv(el) + toDiv(secondHalf[id])).join('')}
`;
```

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(50px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  width: fit-content;
}

#container>div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: tomato;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, was hoping for a CSS-only solution.